# Someone sent me .69 eth from a coinbase account. Should I be concerned?

Tags: transactions, wallets, security, addresses

Im noobish tbh, should I move everything to a hardware wallet? Should I move the eth out of the act so they cant take anything? Im sure I couldve been hacked somehow and someone got my keys. Any ideas? Would it be fine because it came from a coinbase wallet?
Thanks

Comment: The best you could do is educate about how wallets and blockchain work. Mastering Ethereum has a good intro https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have to worry as long as you didn't share mnemonics or your password with anyone. When using blockchain decentralized projects there are lower chances of being hacked.